# Run/compile PApplet from command line in Java

Tags: java, applet

I have the following code, which I can run fine as an applet from within IntelliJ. How would one compile and run it from the command line?

```
package guiModule;

import processing.core.PApplet;

/**
 * Created by Taylor on 9/24/2015.
 */
public class MyDisplay extends PApplet {
    public void setup() {
        size(400, 400);
        background(0,255,0);
    }

    public void draw() {

    }
}
```